# onCheckedChanged vs onCheckStateChanged

Tags: qt, checkbox, qml

What is the difference between `onCheckedChanged` and `onCheckStateChanged`? Both yield the same result when I check/uncheck the box.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Page {

    id : somepageid


    CheckBox {
        checked: true
        text: qsTr("Check Me")
        indicator.width: 15
        indicator.height: 15

        onCheckedChanged: {
            console.log(checked)
        }

        onCheckStateChanged: {
            console.log(checked)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`CheckBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-checkbox.html) can have 3 or 2 states depending on whether the [`tristate`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-checkbox.html#tristate-prop) property is true or not, respectively.

- Unchecked,
- PartiallyChecked, and
- Checked

So `onCheckedChanged` only fires if it goes to Checked or Unchecked state, for example it does not fire if it goes from Unchecked to PartiallyChecked state, unlike `onCheckStateChanged`  which is fired in all cases.